# Symfony2 using jsroutingbundle and got login error

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am using Jsroutingbundle and I add these two lines in my base.html.twig and it works fine.

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

But when I login next time, it jumped to a page like this:

```
fos.Router.setData({"base_url":"\/Symfony\/web\/app_dev.php","routes":[],"prefix":"","host":"localhost","scheme":"http"});
```

And the url is:

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/My/Test/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData
```

I am actually logged in because I can jump to other pages. But it is just unfriendly. How should I handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the access_control of your security add:

```
    - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```